# Specflow: using same step definition for scenario and scenario outline

Tags: cucumber, specflow, gherkin

My feature file contains a 'scenario' test for a successful login and a 'Scenario Outline' test for testing multiple login details which should be unsuccessful.

```
@web
Scenario: Successful login
    Given I have entered username 'tomsmith' and password 'SuperSecretPassword!' into the application
    When I login
    Then I should be informed that login was successful

@web
Scenario Outline: Unsuccessful login
    Given I have entered username <username> and password <password> into the application
    When I login
    Then I should be informed that login was unsuccessful

    Examples: 
    | testing                          | username | password             |
    | invalid combination 1            | test     | test                 |
    | special characters               | $$$      | SuperSecretPassword! |
```

I would like both to use the same step definition (as they are just passing parameters)

My step definition is:

```
[Given(@"I have entered username '(.*)' and password '(.*)' into the application")]
public void GivenIHaveEnteredUsernameAndPasswordIntoTheApplication(string p0, string p1)
{
    login = new LoginPage();
    login.with(p0, p1);
}
```

The problem is that the scenario outline tests do not run, they return a 'Pending' error: *Pending: No matching step definition found for one or more steps*

and suggests the step definition should be:

```
[Given(@"I have entered test and test into the application")]
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you problem is on this line:

```
Given I have entered username <username> and password <password> into the application
```

it should be

```
Given I have entered username '<username>' and password '<password>' into the application
```

you just missed out the `'` marks

Comment: as an aside I'd be tempted to put all of the scenarios into the outline and have a extra column with the result which holds `true` or `false` and change the last the step to 

    `Then I should be informed that a successful login was '<result>'`

but YMMV

Comment: Thank you Sam, that works fine now.  I'll also look at your suggestion to combine the scenarios as that makes far more sense! Thanks again

Comment: Thanks Sam. I can't upvote yet as my reputation is < 15, but I was able to mark the question as answered. I'll make a note to come back and do this once I have the necessary reputation!